# Delete all categories from a product - Mage

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to delete all the categories from a product in Magento. I know they're stored in the `catalog_category_product`-table, but I can't seem to find in any way how I can delete any record in there with Mage.

Hell, I can't even seem to load it.

Here's my code:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $product_row[ 'sku' ] );
if($product) {
    $currentCatIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    $categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $currentCatIds)
                        ->load();

}
```

I thought I could just do `$categoryCollection->delete();` after the above code, but nothing seems to work. Altho imo this code looks totally fine.

Edit: some more info. I don't want to delete the product or the categories linked to the product. I just want to delete the link that `links` the product to the categories, so the product is for example, removed from category `category1`

Could really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER UPDATED**

Why you are calling the **getCategoryIds()** method for the Product model?

Just use the the **setCategoryIds()** from the Product model and later the **save()** method, as follows:

```
$product->setCategoryIds(array());
$product->save();
```

Comment: I think this deleted a bit too much stuff lol. I need to delete the link between the category and the product. The product and the category should not be deleted

Comment: I'm sorry I've confused the request! Check my updated answer, you do not need any collection for do this, simply call the **setCategoryIds()** from the Product model and later the **save()** method ;)

Comment: whow, that would be incredibly simple :) I'll let you know tomorrow if it worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm :)